# Agregar un modulo hecho en React.js a otro sitema

Tags: javascript, reactjs

La cuestion es la siguiente: Mi cliente me solicito realizar un modulo, el cual no es muy grande, consta de un formulario dinamico para creacion de encuestas. En fin, mi cliente me dijo que puedo desarrollarlo en cualquier lenguaje, realizarlo como me sienta mas comodo. Ahora casi terminado me esta preguntando como implementarlo en su sistema(JAMAS ME QUISO DAR INFORMACION DE QUE LENGUAJE UTILIZO EN SU SITEMA).
El modulo que realice lo hice en React.js (ya que es la herramienta con la que me siento comodo).
Ahora bien mi pregunta es: ***Se puede implementar un modulo hecho en react dentro de otro sistema el cual cuenta con varios modulos propios pero no tiene nada que ver con react?***.

Espero la pregunta sea clara.. Si se sienten interesados en responder pero le quedo algun clavo suelto, no tengo problema en charlarlo contal de encontrar alguna respuesta. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo que preguntas es muy interesante, pero al abrir debate/consulta, haces que los que respondan te den sus opiniones... Editalo de tal forma que la pregunta obtenga una respuesta concreta antes que te cierren la pregunta

Comment: Creo que ya edite correctamente

Comment: Te recomiendo que le hagas un ojo a [preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) y sobre todo a [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , claramente esto no se puede responder objetivamente con esa (escasa) información

Answer (score 0):

El problema seria como integrarlo, ya que generalmente los desarrolladores brindan apis para eso, pedile el nombre de la aplicacion que usa, y en base a lo que veas en su codigo, ya sabrias que lenguaje, porque lo mas probable es que si le pedis el lenguaje, no va a tener mucha idea.